# Time to start only after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/98/

is there a way to start timer only after a button is clicked in the given jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/98/

```
var seconds=0;
var Score=0;
var index=0;
countdown(60);

function countdown(sec) {
    seconds = sec;
    tick();
}
function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML = "Time : " + String(seconds);
    if(seconds>60 && Score<30)
    {
        alert("Not enough Score");
    }
    if( seconds > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a function inside the click handler and a variable which states if the function has started or not.

Also you can club the click events inside a single handler and the index can be stored as part of the data-* attributes which reduces duplicated code.

**Javascript**

```
//Timer //

var seconds = 0,
    Score = 0,
    index = 0,
    timerStarted = false;

function countdown(sec) {
    seconds = sec;
    tick();
}

function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML = "Time : " + String(seconds);
    if (seconds > 60 && Score < 30) {
        alert("Not enough Score");
    }
    if (seconds > 0) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }
}

$("#one, #two, #three").click(function () {
    if(!timerStarted) {
        countdown(60);
        timerStarted = true;
    }
    var dataIndex = $(this).data('index');
    if (index == dataIndex) {
        Score++;
        if(dataIndex == 2) {
            index = 0;
        } else {
           index++;   
        }
    } 

    $("#score").html("Score: " + Score);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="score">Score: 0</div>
<button id="one" type="button" data-index="0">Button1</button>
<button id="two" type="button" data-index="2">Button2</button>
<button id="three" type="button" data-index="1">Button3</button>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/98/)**

Comment: why the timer is not showing in first page,if i put the same code in two pages...

Answer (score 0):

```
var seconds=0;
var Score=0;
var index=0;
var started = false;

function countdown(sec) {
    seconds = sec;
    tick();
}
function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML = "Time : " + String(seconds);
    if(seconds>60 && Score<30)
    {
        alert("Not enough Score");
    }
    if( seconds > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }
}

$("button").click(function(){
    if(!started){
        started = true;
        countdown(60);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate custom event after click

`$(window).trigger('clicked');`

```
$(window).on('clicked', function() {
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/100/

Comment: sorry to say that the timer is not running and nothing seems to be working from the jsfiddle link u have given...

Comment: You click button, wait a second and seconds decrease by one.

There also was a mistace, try http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/103/

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to check if the countdown has not started yet.

```
$("button").click(function(){

});
```

This will add a handler to all the buttons in your DOM, then just check the status of the countdown.

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/Bwdfw/102/